# Get Chart soundcloud on Android Studio

Tags: android, soundcloud

How to get chart soundcloud on android studio ? i have a code like this.

```
private String clientId;
private String mPrefixClientId;

//Constants
public static final String BASEURL = "http://api.soundcloud.com/";
public static final String BASEURL2 = "http://api-v2.soundcloud.com/";
public static final String USER="users";
public static final String CHART="charts?kind=top&genre=soundcloud%3Agenres%3A";
public static final String TRACKS="tracks";
public static final String COMMENTS="comments";
public static final String PLAYLISTS="playlists";

public static final String JSON_PREFIX=".json";

public static final String FORMAT_CLIENT_ID="?client_id=%1$s";
public static final String FORMAT_OFFSET="&offset=%1$s&limit=%2$s";
public static final String FORMAT_FILTER_QUERY="&q=%1$s";
public static final String FORMAT_STREAM = "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/%1$s/stream?client_id=%2$s";
```

```
public ArrayList getListTrackObjectsOfUser(long userId, int offset, int limit){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(BASEURL2);
        builder.append(CHART);
        builder.append(String.valueOf(userId)+"&");
        builder.append(mPrefixClientId);
        builder.append(String.format(FORMAT_OFFSET, String.valueOf(offset), String.valueOf(limit)));
        String url = builder.toString();

        return SoundCloudParser.parsingListTrackObject(Helper.getJSONArrayFromUrl(url), this);
    }
```

Call the Soundcloud fragment

```
i.add(new NavItem("SoundCloud", R.drawable.ic_music, NavItem.ITEM, SoundCloudFragment.class,
                new String[]{"pop"}));
```

but the application crashes.
but if I take based on the specific user. applications work well with this kind aray.

```
    public ArrayList getListTrackObjectsOfUser(long userId, int offset, int limit){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(BASEURL);
        builder.append(USER+"/");
        builder.append(String.valueOf(userId)+"/");
        builder.append(TRACKS);
        builder.append(JSON_PREFIX);
        builder.append(mPrefixClientId);
        builder.append(String.format(FORMAT_OFFSET, String.valueOf(offset), String.valueOf(limit)));

        String url = builder.toString();

        return SoundCloudParser.parsingListTrackObject(Helper.getJSONArrayFromUrl(url), this);
    }
```

With Spesific user.
[image: With SPesific user]
anyone have a solution?

Comment: Hey, If you are getting top chart from sound cloud then please help me to get them.. give me some code

Comment: I got top chart API.. But i wanted to add that specifically country based.. like.. if i m from india.. it should show india song.. but... unfortunately i did not get that feature.